# Using ekg with stack while testing

Tags: performance, haskell, haskell-stack

I've written some endurance tests, which I run with `stack test`. I'm also using [`ekg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg) for monitoring the performance. This package recommends:

> To make full use out of this module you must first enable GC statistics collection in the run-time system. To enable GC statistics collection, either run your program with
>
> ```
> +RTS -T
> ```
>
> or compile it with
>
> ```
> -with-rtsopts=-T
> ```

I know that stack supports the `--profile` and `--trace` options, but I couldn't find any option for passing the `+RTS -T` options to the test program. Are there any flags I can use for achieving this effect?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you can pass arguments to the test executable like this: `stack test --test-arguments "my-arg"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark said, use `--test-arguments` to provide command line arguments to your test application:

```sh
stack test --test-arguments="+RTS -T"
```

If you don't use `stack test` but `stack exec`, make sure to disable RTS parsing in `stack` itself:

```sh
stack --RTS exec <executable-name> +RTS <rts-options>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to set the compiler options in the `.cabal` (or `package.yaml` if using `hpack`) file:

```
ghc-options:
# ...
- -with-rtsopts=-N
# ... Add the -T options on top of the other `RTS` options:
- -with-rtsopts=-T
# ...
```

Since the `-T` option has little overhead, this approach does not require to pass any flags to `stack` in order to get relevant `ekg` metrics.